# Android spinner showing middle of screen

Tags: android

Is there a way to force the spinner drop down menu to show directly under the button click?  Right now when I click on the spinner it changes focus to the middle of the screen.

Basic setup for my spinner below:

```
  <Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

Comment: Can you post entire screen?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I used the below and got it working:

```
 android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```